# Reading keyboard input into an array with Groovy

Tags: arrays, input, groovy

I am learning how to do some noobie things with Groovy.I am wondering how to read input from the user into an array of strings that can take 10 words and then print them out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
System.in.withReader { 
        print  'input: ' 
        def userInput = it.readLine()
        println userInput[0]
}
```

This will read the input from the console and print the first character.

Comment: That is good but I need to print out the entire word and take in a list of 10 words.